# How to find rows in excel that that only match a given criteria across all rows where one specific field has duplicates

Tags: excel

If I have a table that looks like the below. How can I get excel to return the breed of dog that only meets the criteria Is_Brown = 0 and never meets the criteria Is_Brown = 1. For example in the case below that would be the Golden Retriever and Bulldog.

| Dog Breed | Is_Brown |
| --- | --- |
| Labrador | 1 |
| Spaniel | 1 |
| Poodle | 0 |
| Labrador | 0 |
| Bulldog | 0 |
| Labrador | 1 |
| Golden Retriever | 0 |
| Poodle | 1 |
| Spaniel | 0 |
| Golden Retriever | 0 |
| Bulldog | 0 |

If I try to filter or use a pivot table and filter on Is_Brown = 0 this would still include those breeds where for that specific row the filter criteria was met but I want the Dog Breed where the criteria applied is ONLY ever met across all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Office 365, this should work (assuming breed is column A and is_brown is column B :

`=FILTER(UNIQUE(A2:A12),SUMIF(A2:A12,UNIQUE(A2:A12),B2:B12)=0)`

- `UNIQUE(A2:A12)` : Returns an array of breeds without duplicates
- `SUMIF(A2:A12,UNIQUE(A2:A12),B2:B12)` : Returns an array of the sum of "is_brown" for each breed
- `=FILTER(UNIQUE(A2:A12),SUMIF(A2:A12,UNIQUE(A2:A12),B2:B12)=0)` : Returns the breed for witch the sum of is_brown is 0

If you are using a table this would also work (assuming your table is called Table1) :
`=FILTER(UNIQUE(Table1[Dog Breed]),SUMIF(Table1[Dog Breed],UNIQUE(Table1[Dog Breed]),Table1[Is_Brown])=0)`

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, you can use a pivot table with `Breed` as rows and `Is_Brown` as summed values.

[image]

Then the breeds you look for are the ones for which the sum is nil, you just filter the rows by value:

[image]

Which gives you the expected output:

[image]